# Thoughtful Foley

Tags: foley, foley-artist

This weekend I went and brought my daughter to see Gnomeo & Juliet.

It was a well done flick. The animation was great, lots of laughs for adults as well as kids and so on, great performances by the voice actors and some awesome cameos (Hulk Hogan and Ozzy Osbourne, how awesome!) but what really caught me was the foley.

Instead of using traditional footsteps they actually used the materials the characters were made out of. ie: in regards to foot steps; ceramic and/or concrete for the Gnomes, what sounded like metal rods for the Flamingo and etc. It was a great touch that really brought it all to life for me. The last thing I was expecting when going to see this was such a standout foley performance. My only gripe is that I wish there were more of it in there, which I'm sure it was... but it was sometimes mixed a little too low for my tastes.

Does anyone know who the foley artist was on that? There isn't one listed on imdb. Only the recordist was listed.

Can anyone name any other examples of your favorite foley that stands out above the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another film with exceptionally characterful foley (& mix) is Winged Migration

If I remember right, the foley artist got a major credit (maybe not front credit, but a card/lead credit) and the work is beautiful, at times the foley turns into the score etc... 
I think it was the same team who also made Microcosmos, another film with beautiful detailed foley, for the amazing macro photography...

Both films are documentaries but not in any usual sense

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0301727/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117040/

(interesting IMDb trivia: "Filmmakers exposed the eggs of some of the birds to the sounds of people and film cameras so that the birds would not be afraid of them later")

Comment: Wow. I wonder if that actually worked? (exposing the eggs)

Comment: Wasn't it Murch who explained hearing as the first sense (before birth) and last (when everything else has shut down)?

Comment: I'll mark this as the "accepted answer" since it completely embodies the type of response I was looking for.

I'm definitely going to have to check this one out now. Where'd you hear that Murch Quote? Wherever it's from I'd love to check that out as well. Especially since I'm a huge Murch fan.

Comment: @Syndicate I believe I answered your question about who the foley artists were...

Comment: @Utopia @Syndicate - I do not get the idea of 'accepted answer' on SSD, and will never mark one for a Q I've asked... Most are opinions, not answers

Comment: @Syndicate Synthetique re the Murch quote, it is from the foreword that he wrote for Michel Chions book 'Audio-Vision'

Comment: @tim I don't really care for the concept either, however I used it in this case since I thought the answer provided a good example of the type of discussion I was trying to provoke (which imo is the intended purpose of that feature). @Utopia yes, you did and I thanks you for that. The question about who the artist was more of a sidenote to the discussion since it was more about examples of exemplary foley. Points and etc. on here are redundant. It's simply about knowledge and good discussion. I did +1 your response though.

Comment: @tim @Syndicate WHAT?!?! I thought I could turn these points in for credit at Sweetwater.com for more gear? I was joking, the "..." I thought would be sufficient but it's hard to insert tongue into cheek with typing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Foley Artist - Jack Stew
Foley Artist - Andrea King
Foley Artist - Nicolas Becker
Foley Mixer - Ed Colyer
Foley Mixer - Adam Mendez
Foley Mixer - Glen Gathard

Go here and you can see the full cast and credit list:

http://movies.nytimes.com/movie/385176/Gnomeo-and-Juliet/credits

Some of the best foley I have ever seen I've mentioned before here is that of "The Lovely Bones".

I love the part in the beginning when Stanley Tucci is building the doll-house and every piece of foley sounded like it was recorded to be it's harshest, and most violent and put the audience on edge just from the foley of building a doll-house. I am pretty sure this quality of recording was planned on purpose.

Comment: Thanks for finding out who the foley artist was. That scene sounds awesome and I'm going to have to check that movie out now since I've yet to see it.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many films where SFX and foley stand out above the rest. I love "UP" for the realism in the foley and it was mixed so well that the images and sound worked beautifully. Also, The Triplets of Bellville (Bellville Rendez-vous) for the foley. fantastic in it's realism and how it worked with the dark animation and the films somber mood.